# Ansys Workbench - adding force in point

Tags: finite-element-method, structural-analysis, ansys

How to add force in certain point. I want to see influence of point force on my structure. (See image)

That force is for example weight of some tank or something similar inside my structure. I don't have suports defined yet. How to define force on x,y,z point in ANSYS Workbrench? Is that possible? Model (geometry) will be imported as STP file  to ANSYS.

Does someone have idea how this can be accomplished.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So if the point isn't a point on your geometry then you can add a **Remote Force**. It is in the loads menu. You will then need to choose a Scoping Method and choose the faces/features of your geometry that the load will be transferred to.

Additionally I think you may need to create that point where the load is applied in your geometry so you can select it as the location of the Remote Force.